# Animate scrollTop on fixed header

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, scroll

I am using the code below, but I would like it to animate so that the phone number scrolls up smoothly similar to way in which the phone numbers in the header do for this website: http://www.lyonsroofing.com

Thank you.

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $("#theFixed").css("top",Math.max(28,45-$(this).scrollTop()));
});
```

```css
 #theFixed {
  position:fixed;
  top:45px;
 }

.container {
    width:100%;
    height:2000px;
  }



#logoright {
 width:240px;
 float:right; 
 text-align:right;
}

.logorightpad { 
 padding: 0; 
}

.social {
 float:right;
 padding:0;
 margin:3px 0 0 0; 
}

.social-left {
 float:left; 
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="logoright">
<div class="logorightpad">

<div id="theFixed">
<div class="telephone">
<h2>555-555-1212</h2>
</div>
<div class="social">
<div class="social-right"><a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com><i class="fa fa-facebook-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get smooth transition effect using css transition or jquery animate.

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $("#theFixed").css("top",Math.max(28,45-$(this).scrollTop()));
});
```

```css
#theFixed {
  position:fixed;
  top:45px;
 /* added transition*/
  -webkit-transition: top 0.5s;
         transition: top 0.5s;
 }

.container {
    width:100%;
    height:2000px;
  }



#logoright {
 width:240px;
 float:right; 
 text-align:right;
}

.logorightpad { 
 padding: 0; 
}

.social {
 float:right;
 padding:0;
 margin:3px 0 0 0; 
}

.social-left {
 float:left; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="logoright">
<div class="logorightpad">

<div id="theFixed">
<div class="telephone">
<h2>555-555-1212</h2>
</div>
<div class="social">
<div class="social-right"><a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com><i class="fa fa-facebook-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  
</div> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I just added `transition: top 0.5s;` to your css.

Comment: Updated answer slightly to add vendor prefix for webkit to be sure, that it would work on all supported browser. If this solution works for you consider marking it as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

use jquery animate : http://api.jquery.com/animate/
Something like shoule work : 
    $("#theFixed").animate({"top",Math.max(28,45-$(this).scrollTop())});